# Azure durable functions sample says sync functions are not allowed

Tags: azure

I'm stepping through Azure training.  I'm currently looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-long-running-serverless-workflow-with-durable-functions/4-exercise-create-a-workflow-using-durable-functions .

When I got to "Verify that the durable functions workflow starts" I noticed something was wrong.  Instead of the json response that it predicted, I got a blank screen.  Then, I checked the log of the HttpStart function, and I saw this:

```
Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
```

I'm not sure where I would do that, but at this point I went through all of the previous instructions looking for variances.  The only thing I noticed was that in the instructions, where it showed what the "function.json" for HttpStart should look like, I noticed it had this:

```
"authLevel": "anonymous",
```

But I had this:

```
"authLevel": "function",
```

What I have seems more correct, in any case, so I think what was shown in the instructions was incorrect.

I also noticed that the instructions described installing the "Azure DurableTask extension", but I didn't see any prompt to install this.

I didn't see any other variances from the instructions.

I then googled the error message.  The following seems relevant, but I don't know how or whether this really applies: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7644 .

Comment: I just hit the same issue.  I also was not greeted with a window to install the "Azure DurableTask extension".  I have tried reverting my runtime to version 2 but that did not fix the issue (by doing that the function did not start)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

forget the last sentence of my comment above regarding reverting to version 2.

I have changed my runtime version to version 2 and this time the HTTP Trigger was successful in running.  To change the runtime version, I clicked on the "Function App settings" link underneath the Configured features heading on the Overview tab of the durable function I created [image: overview tab]

In the Function app settings tab, I selected the ~2 button to change the runtime version to 2.0.xxxx
[image: app settings tab]

Also, just to make sure the durable functions package was installed, I ran

> npm view durable-functions

Comment: To be clear, it starts out with version "~3", and you changed it to version "~2"?

Comment: I confirm that this workaround fixed my problem.  I went through the whole sequence, determined that the response from "OrchFunction" was empty (I didn't check the logs this time). I then went back to the settings you specify here, changed the version from ~3 to ~2, then simply refreshed the tab where I executed the OrchFunction, and that gave me the expected response, and everything worked from then on.

Comment: Yes David, the function is set to version 3 when Azure creates it and I changed it to version 2 after.  I have provided Azure Learning with feedback regarding this issue so hopefully it will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: Thanks. I had already asked Azure Support.  Note that the next exercise after this also has issues, which I also posted about. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104100/azure-durable-timer-exercise-never-hits-the-timeout

Comment: I was also having similar problems and followed you suggested fix .. Could you explain why changing to ~2 fixes the issue?

Comment: version 3 is .NET Core 3.  From the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#http-synchronous-io-disabled-in-all-servers  "Starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0, synchronous server operations are disabled by default"

Comment: Thanks - I submitted feedback to Azure Learning so hopefully it'll be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround without changing the azure SDK version is to add a compatibility app setting and setting it to true.

Go to:

- Platform Features
- Configurations
- Function Runtime Settings and
- add FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE and set it to true

This seems to do the trick while the azure-functions-durable package gets this fixed to deal with synchronous calls within the library, see the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/175)