# Azure durable timer exercise never hits the timeout

Tags: azure

I'm stepping through Azure training. I'm currently looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-long-running-serverless-workflow-with-durable-functions/6-exercise-add-a-durable-timer-to-manage-a-long-running-task .

Going through this exercise requires going through the previous exercise, which I had issues with, which I asked about at [Azure durable functions sample says sync functions are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019624/azure-durable-functions-sample-says-sync-functions-are-not-allowed) .  The answer to that question let me go on to the next step.  You have to do both of these exercises in the same sandbox session.

I set up all the settings as described in the exercise, and I got to "Verify that the Durable Functions workflow starts".

When I clicked on the "statusQueryGetUri" url, I got the following response:

```
{
  "name": "OrchFunction",
  "instanceId": "5bb6bd9607544adbbc7d6aa00b7a2d40",
  "runtimeStatus": "Running",
  "input": null,
  "customStatus": null,
  "output": null,
  "createdTime": "2020-02-06T21:41:11Z",
  "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-02-06T21:41:35Z"
}
```

The exercise said I should see this:

```
{
  "instanceId": "dc3e6d7c2943474dad2af479233c02e4",
  "runtimeStatus": "Pending",
  "input": null,
  "customStatus": null,
  "output": null,
  "createdTime": "2019-04-14T13:17:26Z",
  "lastUpdatedTime": "2019-04-14T13:17:27Z"
}
```

As the exercise specified, I let it sit for 20 seconds before doing anything.  I'm sure I waited longer than that.  I refreshed the URL, and it basically did nothing.  I got the same response.  I've tried several times afterwards, and it still just says "Running", and I never get the expected escalation output.

Answer (score 0):

It's been solved in the meantime, I got this response:

```
{
    "name": "OrchFunction",
    "instanceId": "f31cae1e3791451ab8bd52d78ad4ed0a",
    "runtimeStatus": "Completed",
    "input": null,
    "customStatus": null,
    "output": [
        "ESCALATION : You have not approved the project design proposal - reassigning to your Manager!  Head of department!"
    ],
    "createdTime": "2020-03-11T13:18:38Z",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2020-03-11T13:19:14Z"
}
```